# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer, browser-automation

The problem is that I have a function in puppeteer that returns a list of objects but when I want to analyze it it tells me that it is null or undefined.

```
  await page.waitForSelector(('.carousel .loaded'), { timeout: 90000 })
  const _img = await page.evaluate(
  () => document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .loaded li'));
```

when I analyze the answer it tells me that it is null.

```
 if( Object.keys(_img).length > 0){ //do }

 if( _img.length > 0){ //do }
```

If I repeat the queries in the browser console it works.

Comment: Please use English to ask a question.

Comment: Unfortunately, [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) can only transfer serializable values (roughly, the values JSON can handle). `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a collection of DOM elements that is not serializable. You need to return either serializable value (an array of texts, etc) or use something like [`page.$$(selector)`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) and [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) API.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was as [@vsemozhebuty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2625560/vsemozhebuty) said:

> Unfortunately, [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) can only transfer serializable values (roughly, the values JSON can handle). `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a collection of DOM elements that is not serializable. You need to return either serializable value (an array of texts, etc) or use something like [`page.$$(selector)`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) and [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) API.

I had to return a serializable value (an array of texts, etc):

```
await page.waitForTimeout(5000)
const _img = await page.evaluate(
  () => 
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .loaded li [role="img"]')).map((d) => d.getAttribute('class'))
  );
```